# IBM Filenet P8 Integrated windows Auth

Tags: .net, web-services, windows-authentication, filenet-p8

A colleague of mine is trying to consume an intranet web service that's configured to use Integrated Windows Auth and he believes there's no way to configure IBM Filenet P8 to perform integrated Windows Auth.

I am very doubtful of that but everything I see in Google seems to be related to IBM File Net Share Point Connector. Is that the same thing?

Can anybody confirm that yes indeed, Integrated Windows Auth is not supported in IBM File NET P8?

If there's a way, can you provide quick steps on how to do this?

I don't use IBM Filenet P8 and I don't need to/want to know. I just want my colleague to be able to consume the web service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you are asking could mean any of several possibilities, but it probably does not refer to the IBM FileNet SharePoint Connector.  The most likely thing that your colleague is facing is wanting to use web services to communicate with a FileNet P8 Content Engine (CE) or Process Engine (PE).

Both of those servers do indeed have web services exposed (referred to as CEWS and PEWS, respectively).  And, both of them can work with IWA.  From your question, it sounds like the server is already set up, and your colleague is trying to figure out the details of what to do in his client piece (or, rather, that he believes it simply cannot be done).

The details are bit much to go into here, but here are a couple of pieces of info that will hopefully send him down the right path.  (I realize you weren't looking for a homework assignment; sorry! :-)

Here is the official product documentation, including the developer guide:  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v5r1m0/index.jsp  It's searchable, so searching for terms like "integrated windows authentication" or "kerberos" will turn up some interesting links.

Here is a free IBM Redbook specifically about developing with P8:  *Developing Applications with IBM FileNet P8 APIs*, http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/SG247743.html

Unless your colleague is in a position where the interface just must be web services, I would encourage him to look into the P8 CE .NET API.  It's a full .NET compatible API, with all the niceties of OO and type safety that are sometimes a little awkward in web services work.  It talks to the same CEWS listener that he is probably trying to use with web services.  It's also pretty easy to get IWA going with that API.

Comment: thanks for the links. They are helpful. None of `googleing` brought me to those links. Finally my co-worker resolved his issue. This is what he said: `filenet has what it calls java components`
`it enables you to write your own code`. So I am happy :). I will accept your answer.